# Throw multiple exceptions in Java when working with I/O

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am parsing data from a txt file in Java using Buffered Reader. I want to throw multiple exceptions but dont know what is the best way to do this.

```
public class GameLoader {

    public GameLoader() {
    }

    /**
     * Loads a game grid from a text file.
     *
     * @param reader a {@code Reader} object that reads from the text file
     * @return the loaded game grid
     * @throws IOException if there is an error reading from the file
     * @throws FileFormatException if the file format is invalid
     */
    public static GameGrid load(Reader reader) throws IOException, FileFormatException {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        // functionality 
           

    }

}
```

Here are my throws:

Throws:

```
IOException - if there is an error reading from the reader
FileFormatException - if the file is not in the correct format, 
NullPointerException - if reader is null
```

FileFormatExceotion is custom defined.

I tried using multiple try statement but IntelliJ told me that the catch statement will never be reached.
I want to throw IOexception or NullPointerException early at the buffered reader stage then when my functionality code fails is due to the incorrect File Formating and when that happens I can throw FileFormatException().

Just to clarify
I want to throw the IOException - if there is an error reading from the reader, if there is no reading error, I want to throw NullPointerException - if reader is null and I want to throw FileFormatException - when the main body of my code fails

[image]

also

[image]

Comment: What exceptions do you want to throw?  Do you want to catch exception 'X' from BufferedReader and throw exception 'Y instead, for various values of X and Y?  Then catch specific exceptions, not 'everything without distinction'.

Comment: You know you can write `try { ... } catch (X1 x) { ... } catch (X2 x) { ... }`, where X1 and X2 are exception types, right?

Comment: @ArfurNarf I want to throw the IOException - if there is an error reading from the reader, if there is no reading error, I want to throw NullPointerException - if reader is null and I want to throw FileFormatException - when the main body of my code fails

Comment: @ArfurNarf Yes I tried that but it did not work, my FileFormatException(), will never be reached said IntelliJ Idea

Comment: Please post the code you wrote, I can't really guess what you're doing.

Comment: Do not catch NullPointerException.  Throwing a new exception discards, and effectively obliterates, the original NullPointerException’s stack trace, which makes it impossible to find out which line of code caused the problem.  Just remove that particular catch block entirely, and let the original NullPointerException propagate naturally.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static GameGrid load(Reader reader) throws IOException, FileFormatException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(reader, "reader cannot be null");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    // Code functionality - that creates gameGrid, reads lines, etc.
    // Here, while trying to read the buffer, validate the format of the lines,
    // if the format is not as per expectation, then explicitly
    if(!isLineValid(line)) {
        throw new FileFormatException("some detail regarding format");
    }
    return gameGrid;
}
```

No need to explicitly throw `IOException`. It will be raised by the `bufferedReader.readLine()` (or other) calls from inside, if it faces an issue reading from the `reader` object.

In your code snippet, you have:

```
} catch(FileFormatException e) {
    throw new FileFormatException("File is not in the correct format", e);
}
```

If this is your custom exception `FileFormatException`, then nothing else will raise it and you don't have to catch it. You yourself have to throw it.  So, it will be just

```
        throw new FileFormatException("File is not in the correct format");
```

Based on your own validation routine of the lines read.

Update.. Based on discussion over comments...

```
public static GameGrid load(Reader reader) throws IOException, FileFormatException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(reader, "reader cannot be null");
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        // Code functionality - that creates gameGrid, reads lines, etc.
        return gameGrid;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new FileFormatException("File is not in the correct format", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain why it is indented? I have never seen this kind of notation before

Comment: Also I added your FileFormatException() code and it is not working, it says that the return gamGrid; will not be reached

Comment: That `throw new FileFormatException` has tobe conditional. Inside some `if` condition - thrown only if the format validation determines that the line read is not in the correct format. It is a custom exception as you said, so it won't be raised by Java itself. You have to raise your own after validation.  If you always raise it without any condition, then it won't reach the next line.

Comment: @Ishan can I just create a general exception like catch ```(Exception e) {throw new FileFormatException();} ```instead of FileFormatException

Comment: @Chaosfire, `and you can use try-with-resources without catching exceptions to release the resource automatically` - that should not be used here.  `reader` is coming from outside this method. If you put BufferedReader in `try-with-resource` - it will be closed here. Ideally, the caller of this method should close the `reader` in its own scope.

Comment: @AliceRathbone, If you do that, IOException will also be caught and FileFormatException will be raised. If you want to use FileFormatException, then it has to be specifically based on the validation of the format of the content read from the `reader` object. Not any generic `Exception` caught - which could be raised for any other reason, not related to file format too.

Comment: @Ishan thanks for that, is there a work around other than specically based on the validation of the format of the content read, my code is very specific to the format already, so any errors must be FileFormatException. Can I do ```catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FileFormatException();
        }``` So now using two catch, would that work?

Comment: @Ishan Good point, releasing in the caller would be better indeed.

Comment: @AliceRathbone, Yes, if there is no specific logic to detect format error, then yes, you can do this: ```catch (IOException e) {             throw e;         } catch (Exception e) {             throw new FileFormatException("Not in correct format", e);         }```